# Minifying html breaks page

Tags: html, web, minify

I am trying to optimize my mobile site and one of the things i am trying to do is minimize the html code (css and javascript are already minified)
after minifying i have noticed issues with how the page looks 
nothing too dramatic, but here is an example:
[image: top is how it should look, bottom is how it looks after minifying the page]

What causes my page to break when it is minified, and how can i minify the page without it breaking?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what causes this, and how can i minify the code without it breaking the page?

sorry XD

Comment: I bet you're missing a semicolon in one of your CSS statements and the minifier is breaking that declaration.

Comment: Try copying the generated HTML (with, e.g., Chrome's Developer Tools)  and minifying that. Web browsers are probably cleaning up your HTML, which has some sort of error in it, by guessing what you meant. Does your HTML validate? validator.w3.org

Comment: CSS is minified, and it isn't breaking anything, it's only when i minify the html.
i will use chromes dev tools, and make a new page from that code and see how that goes

Comment: i used pagespeed, and used that to optimize(minify) the html code...the page looked fine, but when i validated it with validator.w3.org there were 544 errors and 49 warnings, compared to 139 and 49 before minifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem I have is that whitespace in HTML *sometimes* adds visible spacing. It's clear that the two tags below will render differently:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<p>Helloworld</p>
```

And so will these:

```
<p>Hello
world</p>
<p>Helloworld</p>
```

The minifier will might remove line breaks, which might change spacing. See if a line break is somehow essential to your page's layout.

Comment: Excellent - didn't think that the whitespace could alter the layout!